# Files being created in the wrong folder

Tags: c++, eclipse, path, fstream

To give a little context: I'm writing a program that uses text files and BMP files. For the text files I was provided with a class to manage them and I'm using EasyBMP for the BMP manipulation. 
The problem I have is the files are being created in the wrong folder unless I provide the full path.

Example:

```
#include "EasyBMP.h"
int main(){
    BMP picture;
    picture.SetSize(640,480);
    picture.WriteToFile("picture.BMP");
return 0;
}
```

Expected result: 640x480 BMP file created somewhere in my project folder (C:\Users[user]\Documents\C++\TP 1)

Actual result: 640x480 BMP file created in Eclipse folder (C:\Users[user]\Documents\Eclipse)

The same happens with any other file I write to disk.
It used to work fine on a different project so I'm guessing there's something silly I'm missing somewhere but I haven't been able to find a solution.

EDIT: The exact same code works fine on a different project.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a full pathname, files are stored in the process's current folder. You can change that in Eclipse (tell if which folder to run from when you run the process).

If you always want the files to be stored where your EXE is, or somewhere around the EXE, you can find the folder yourself(the first argument to main is the location of the EXE file).

Answer (score 0):

The program will write the file in the working directory. That's because you used a relative path and relative paths are relative to the working directory.

Either specify a full path in your code, or ensure that the working directory is set to your desired value when running the program.

Comment: Where do you want the file to be written? The working directory, or the directory with the exe file?

Comment: Apparently the magic word(s) I didn't know were "working directory". Didn't know what it was, googled, problem solved. For the sake of helping my ignorance, how do I write to the directory with the exe file?

Comment: That is platform dependent. However, are you sure you want to do that? On most systems, executable files are often stored in read only directories. Normally console apps write in their working directory. That's a very well established convention. What is your program really doing?